# Freeradius service not working : Process: 6181 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, freeradius

I have took over a radius server from a colleague, and he used freeradius 2.2.8.

I have installed freeradius 3.0.16 on a linux Ubuntu 18.04 with `sudo apt-get install freeradius` but when I try to use his old config files, my freeradius service is not starting.

As you can see below, I got 2 errors.

I'm not really an expert in this topic.

Is there anyone can help me guiding to the right way?

Many thanks in advance.

```
admin@ubuntu-de-01:/etc$ service freeradius status
● freeradius.service - FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/freeradius.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-11-07 10:13:24 CET; 3s ago
     Docs: man:radiusd(8)
           man:radiusd.conf(5)
           http://wiki.freeradius.org/
           http://networkradius.com/doc/
  Process: 8651 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

admin@ubuntu-de-01:/etc/freeradius$ sudo /usr/sbin/freeradius -C -lstdout -xxx


/etc/freeradius/3.0/modules/otp
Thu Nov  7 10:15:30 2019 : Debug: including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/modules/krb5
Thu Nov  7 10:15:30 2019 : Debug: including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/modules/unix
Thu Nov  7 10:15:30 2019 : Debug: including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/modules/sql_log
Thu Nov  7 10:15:30 2019 : Error: /etc/freeradius/3.0/modules/sql_log[79]: Syntax error: Expected comma after 'UPDATE radacct     SET        acctstoptime       =  '%S',             acctsessiontime    =  unix_timestamp('%S') -                                  unix_timestamp(acctstarttime),       acctterminatecause =  '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}',        acctstopdelay      =  %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}       WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL      AND nasipaddress      =  '%{NAS-IP-Address}'       AND acctstarttime     <= '%S'': "
Thu Nov  7 10:15:30 2019 : Error: Errors reading or parsing /etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf


sql_log from line 70 to 79:

    Accounting-On = "UPDATE ${acct_table} \
      SET \
         acctstoptime       =  '%S', \
         acctsessiontime    =  unix_timestamp('%S') - \
                               unix_timestamp(acctstarttime), \
         acctterminatecause =  '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}', \
         acctstopdelay      =  %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0} \
      WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL \
      AND nasipaddress      =  '%{NAS-IP-Address}' \
      AND acctstarttime     <= '%S'""
```

Answer (score 1):

close with ;" instead of "" :

```
Accounting-On = "UPDATE ${acct_table} \
  SET \
  acctstoptime       =  '%S', \
 acctsessiontime    =  unix_timestamp('%S') - \
                       unix_timestamp(acctstarttime), \
 acctterminatecause =  '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}', \
 acctstopdelay      =  %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0} \
 WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL \
AND nasipaddress      =  '%{NAS-IP-Address}' \
AND acctstarttime     <= '%S';"
```

Comment: Correct, the parser is getting pissy because you closed one string and then immediately opened another without any associated config item.  Honestly though, you don't even need the semi colon, just remove the second double quote.